# How can I time an event to happen after a 'scrollBehaviour: smooth' animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll

When [`ScrollToOptions.behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions/behavior) is set to 'smooth', a [supporting browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scroll-behavior) will smoothly scroll the page for you, but I am not sure what the timing of the animation is. I need to move focus *after* the animation (because doing it before will jump the scroll and cancel the animation). If it's always a set duration I can just use that, but if it depends on the distance scrolled or changes from browser to browser, I might have to figure out something a little more fancy.

In order to do this I might also need to figure out a way to check for ScrollToOptions support, though at least in Safari it just fails silently

```
  if (options.smooth) {
    let scrollTiming = 250; // ?????

    window.scrollTo({
      top: element.offsetTop - fixedOverlay,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      element.focus();
    }, scrollTiming);
  } else {
    element.focus();
  }
```

Comment: I can't think of anything other than what's been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827193/detect-when-scrolling-has-finished-when-using-scroll-behavior-smooth

Answer (score 0):

Since `window.scrollTo()` emit `scroll` events just like when user scrolls, could you create a custom `scrollend` event by tracking when the regular scroll event stop being emitted?

```
const removeScrollEndListener = (function() {
  let timer = null;
  const event = new Event('scrollend');

  const attachEvent = () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {window.dispatchEvent(event)}, 100)};

  window.addEventListener('scroll', attachEvent);

  return window.removeEventListener.bind(window, 'scroll', attachEvent);
})();

window.addEventListener('scrollend', () => {
  console.log(`scroll end, ${window.scrollY}`)
})

// later, remove custom event
removeScrollEndListener();
```