# Second nav item gets active class when going from first to third

Tags: javascript

So I got this nav highlighting scroll function, after I added a new function that takes me to desired section I am facing this issue.

Whenever I'm on first button and I click on 3rd element for , I can see a flash of red background on the second button (you can see that as well when you scroll manually). This is happening because scroll function keeps triggering every time it's scrolling. Is there way to avoid this? I tried adding a transition time css, but it keeps re-triggering every time I scroll.

```js
function goTo(element) {
      element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
```

```js
const sectionOne = document.querySelectorAll('.observe');
const buttonList = document.querySelectorAll('button')
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

function myScroll(e) {
  let current = ""
  sectionOne.forEach((item) => {
    if (box.scrollTop >= (item.offsetTop - 50)) {
      current = item.getAttribute("id")
    }
  })

  buttonList.forEach((button) => {
    button.classList.remove("bg-red-500")
    if (button.classList.contains(current)) {
      button.classList.add("bg-red-500")
    }
  })

}
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.observe {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.bg-red-500 {
  background: red;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="flex">
    <button class="ob1">
      1st
      </button>
    <button class="ob2">
      2nd
      </button>
    <button class="ob3">
      3rd
      </button>

  </div>
  <div class="box" onscroll="myScroll()">
    <div id="ob1" class="observe">
      1. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div id="ob2" class="observe">
      2. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div id="ob3" class="observe">
      3. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 3. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
      printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
      of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 3. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
      has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
      remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 3. Lorem
      Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827193/detect-when-scrolling-has-finished-when-using-scroll-behavior-smooth

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following. This is a hacky solution and you will need to increase timeout if there will be more content in the future.

```js
const sectionOne = document.querySelectorAll('.observe');
const buttonList = document.querySelectorAll('button')
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

let isAutoScroll = false

function higlightCurrentSectionButton () {
  if(isAutoScroll) return 
  
  let current = ""
  sectionOne.forEach((item) => {
    if (box.scrollTop >= (item.offsetTop - 50)) {
      current = item.getAttribute("id")
    }
  })

  buttonList.forEach((button) => {
    button.classList.remove("bg-red-500")
    if (button.classList.contains(current)) {
      button.classList.add("bg-red-500")
    }
  })
}

function myScroll() {
  higlightCurrentSectionButton()
}

function goTo(id) {
      isAutoScroll = true
      
      var element = document.getElementById(id);
      element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      
      setTimeout(function() {
        isAutoScroll = false
        higlightCurrentSectionButton()
      }, 500);
    }
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.observe {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bg-red-500 {
  background: red;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="flex">
    <button class="ob1" onclick="goTo('ob1')">
      1st
      </button>
    <button class="ob2"  onclick="goTo('ob2')">
      2nd
      </button>
    <button class="ob3" onclick="goTo('ob3')">
      3rd
      </button>

  </div>
  <div class="box" onscroll="myScroll()">
    <div id="ob1" class="observe">
      1. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div id="ob2" class="observe">
      2. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div id="ob3" class="observe">
      3. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 3. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
      printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
      of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 3. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
      has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
      remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 3. Lorem
      Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The more appropriate solution would be to use [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) and change the flag on the intersection that happened.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, because the value is true all the time after scrolling once

Comment: Whenever Im on item `1` and I click item `3`, whenever it scrolls automatically, I do not want to see red background of second button.

I tried using Intersection Observer API for this, but people on stack hated me for it and said I only need scroll listener for this

Comment: @IDrinkCokeRn, sorry. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: @DimitriiZolotuhin but how I am supposed to add color to button in `goTo` function, when all logic for this I have in `myScroll` function?

Comment: @IDrinkCokeRn, added example. You can try to run it to see how it works now. But as I mentioned above it is a kind of a hacky solution.